# Generate non-fragmenting UUIDs in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, uuid

If I understand correctly, fully-random UUID values create fragmented indexes. Or, more precisely, the lack of a common prefix prevents dense trie storage in the indexes.

I've seen a suggestion to use uuid_generate_v1() or uuid_generate_v1mc() instead of uuid_generate_v4() to avoid this problem.

However, it seems that Version 1 of the UUID spec has the *low* bits of the ID first, preventing a shared prefix. Also, this timestamp is 60 bits, which seems like it may be overkill.

By contrast, some databases provide non-standard UUID generators with a timestamp in the leading 32-bits and then 12 bytes of randomness. See Datomic's Squuid's for example [1](http://docs.datomic.com/identity.html#sec-6), [2](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/squuid).

Does it in fact make sense to use "Squuids" like this in Postgres? If so, how can I generate such IDs efficiently with pgplsql?

Comment: As you insert or update more data, you might get the index fragmented, which means that your B+Tree, if you are using a normal index, gets less balanced. Of course you can reindex to make the tree more balanced. From your question, I assume that you want to see which UUID version gets the tree more balanced. I think you should run some benchmarks using [pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/pgbench.html) to see if there is a difference in performance cost and if the plan is generated well. If any of the solutions work for your app then the rest is purely academic study.

Comment: _prevents dense trie storage in the indexes_: why assume trie storage? Typically you'd use a B-tree index for UUIDs. You would get trie storage only if asking for it, through the `text_ops` operator family of the `SP-GiST` type of index.

Comment: I answer a question like this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274038/180382). Basically I suggest [ULIDs](https://github.com/ulid/spec).

Answer (score 3):

Note that inserting sequential index entries will result in a denser index only if you don't delete values and all your updates produce [*heap only tuples*](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT).

If you want sequential unique index values, why not build them yourself?

You could use `clock_timestamp()` in microseconds as `bigint` and append values from a cycling sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 999 CYCLE;

SELECT CAST(
          floor(
             EXTRACT(epoch FROM t)
          ) AS bigint
       ) % 1000000 * 1000000000
     + CAST(
          to_char(t, 'US') AS bigint
       ) * 1000
     + nextval('seq')
FROM (SELECT clock_timestamp()) clock(t);
```

Comment: To avoid confusion for others -- `clock_timestamp()` returns a `timestamp with time zone` that has accuracy to the microsecond. It's not possible to get nanosecond accuracy in pgsql; this code just multiplies the microsecond value by 1000.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix the description.